# Reorder customer details in WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, email-notifications

I am trying to change the order of the customer details fields displayed in the Woocommerce mail sent to both customer and admin after purchase (table name: addresses).

I checked the file responsible of outputting the billing & shipping fields which is `plugins/woocommerce/templates/email-customer-details.php` but the customer details are outputted only through a foreach loop and the variable `$fields` is not even there.

```
<?php foreach ( $fields as $field ) : ?>
  <li><strong><?php echo wp_kses_post( $field['label'] ); ?>:</strong> <span class="text"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $field['value'] ); ?></span></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So, where to change the order of the fields? In particular, I'd like to display the state before the zipcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an available filter hook for that.

It's  included in [`WC_Emails` `customer_details()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.9.2/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L540-L563), which is used to call the template `email-customer-details.php` on all related main email templates.

You can use it this way *(where `$fields` is the array of fields that you want to sort)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields', 'filter_email_customer_details_fields', 10, 3 );
function filter_email_customer_details_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    // Do something

    return $fields;
}
```

For usage, [see those related on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields)